# Side element fixes to top of page once scrolled to

Tags: css, element, fixed

I'm not even sure I'm describing this properly, but basically I want to display a leaderboard ad the way www.okcupid.com has setup.

I found this question helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally) but it stays fixed.  I would prefer it to scroll with the page until it reaches the top and then be fixed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use JavaScript.

The element will have normal flow on your page, and when the `document.body.scrollTop` is larger than the element's `y` position, give it `position: fixed`.

Comment: Don't you mean `position: fixed`?

Comment: @Wesley Whoops, yes. I just got out of bed :P

Comment: I had a feeling. I don't know too much javascript, but that should give me a good starting point ... Thanks!