# Div with fixed position moving relative to margin:auto elements

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a div with a fixed position, but I want it to stay in the same position when my browser screen is increased or decreased in width. Since I have `margin:auto` acting on the surrounding html objects, it changes its position relative to the surrounding objects. I do not want this to happen. How can I fix this?

This is my css so far:

```
position:fixed;
top:45px;
left:930px;
```

Comment: what top/left/bottom/right have you set on the fixed element ?

Comment: I added my css for the div....

Comment: you will need to set its `left` with a percentage value so that it follows the rest of the elements

Comment: That sort of works, but when the margin for the full website is finished the div keeps moving but the rest of the elements do not.

Comment: can you re-create this simply in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post it here so we can see it in action ?

Comment: here's a crude example: http://jsfiddle.net/v84Vz/1/ try expanding your browser window all the way in width and notice that the yellow div with a fixed position eventually overlaps with the green div with a `margin:auto`. That shouldn't happen. The yellow div should behave like it has a margin:auto horizontally but have a fixed position for it's vertical position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your third comment, I believe you might find my solution to a previous problem similar to this to be your solution: [Position element fixed vertically, absolute horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally/3303944#3303944).