# Fixed Text allign with responsive image

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, text-alignment

Im trying to get a column of text to align to a responsive image but I need the text to be fixed so that when you scroll, you can still see the text.I tried having the text relative to the image but It wouldn't stay fixed when scrolling.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="imgcontainer">
<div id="img2">
    <img src="http://www.gabrielamagana.com/ndxz-studio/site/sample/blue_drink_01.jpg" style="max-width:95%;">
    <div id="img3">
        <img src="http://www.gabrielamagana.com/ndxz-studio/site/sample/blue_drink_01.jpg" style="max-width:95%;">
        <div id="img4">
            <img src="http://www.gabrielamagana.com/ndxz-studio/site/sample/blue_drink_01.jpg" style="max-width:95%;">
            <div id="description" style="width:25%">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
#imgcontainer {
margin-top: 96px;
margin-left: 314px;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
}

#img2 {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
position: static;
z-index:1;

}

#img3 {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
position: static;
z-index:1;

}

#img4 {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
position: static;
z-index:1;

}

 #description {
padding-right:50px
float: right;
position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
Left: 900px;

}
```

Here is a clearer idea of what I have (I used a plugin to make the images responsive):

http://jsfiddle.net/rLzc8/

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: Can you make some picture to make clear where do you whant to place your text?

Comment: HI Oleg, I just want the text on the aligned to the right border of the image. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you whant to fix your text vertically, but not horizontally?

Comment: Correct! I want it to move position as the edge of the image moves, but remain fixed vertically for the scroll.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally

Comment: Unfortunately, that works when the object is moving but not when its resizing like my images. The text is fixed to scroll but it doesn't move when the image resizes.

Comment: Why are all your divs nested?

Comment: In the fiddle, you have a missing semicolon between `padding-right:50px` and `float: right;`. Not sure if that solves anything though.

Comment: My divs are nested in a wrapper div "imgcontainer."