# Floating bar when table width is more than 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a long table that has a width of 140%. The header I've added only stretches across the window but does not cover the last few items on the right-hand side of the table. If I (horizontal) scroll to the right, the header does not scroll with the page. I'm sure this can be done but I'm not sure how.

```
   if ($va == '1') { echo '<div class="myFloatBar" align="center"><strong>Viewing Location</strong></div>'; }
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.myFloatBar{
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   position:fixed;
   background-color:#0099ff;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   height: 20px;
   font-size: 15px;
   }
```

How do I get the bar to be the width of the table AND scroll horizontally?

Comment: you should give an exemple of your issue. HTML would help to know where to fix this. position:fixed refers to windows.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for solution through jquery OR Javascript. find the width of the table and set the width of the bar accordingly.

Comment: I know my table is set for 140% as the width. Does that help?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas Difficult to say what the problem is without the HTML for your table, too. Because the code you've given us so far works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lo7b1pzq/

Comment: Using your example, I want the text of 'Viewing Location' to move to the left when I move the scrollbar to the right.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the "Viewing Location" text does not move to the left when you move the scrollbar to the right is because of `position: fixed;`. If you remove this, the element will be given the default `static` position and will move as you expect.

And if you know the `width` of the table is `140%`, why not change the `width` of the header to `140%`?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kmoe/fLyhkemv/

Comment: Yes, it scrolls horizontally just right. But now, when I scroll down, the header stays at the top -- which would be fine but it doesn't follow the page. Is this beyond CSS?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - you want it `fixed` in one dimension only... According to this question, it may be beyond CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally