# How to make horizonatal scroll work on Navbar in Non-responsive Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to create pure non-responsive template using bootstrap,

example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

above example is working great, but if i resize the browser window to small size then horizontal scroll bar is shown but when i move the scroll bar to right, it doesnt show the navbar contents at right side, the navbar doesnt scroll.

how do imake the navbar too scroll, so i can see the right side contents on the NavBar.

i have tried adding the

```
overflow:scroll;
```

`.navbar-fixed-top` but it adds scrollbar to the navbar .

Comment: The issue appears to be the `position: fixed` on the navbar.  Does this solution help at all?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `nav` is `fixed` extra links will be hidden so you can make the nav static

you will need to change the class from `navbar-fixed-top` to `navbar-static-top`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
```

or you will need to write your own css to make the `nav` `width` `100%`