# Center div in viewport with scrolling

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to center a header and footer in the viewport (like the game below). Content scrolls both vertically and horizontally but the header and footer should stay in the same place on the viewport. I've tried using following CSS:

```
.BottomMenu {
    background-color: #ADADAD;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

But this produces a footer that is sticky *vertically* only. I need it to stay in that spot while the content moves in *any* direction.

[image: Example 1]

Comment: Could you link a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, I believe, is your `left` and `right` values. The code below will do the trick.

```css
body {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 5000px;
}

#element {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  border: solid orange 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

The `translate` method adjusts the position of the element relative to itself. For instance, if you had an element with a `width: 100px` and set `transform: translateX(-50%)`, it would move the element `50px` to the left of wherever it is positioned.

```
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
```

Works like so...

```
 _________________
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|_________________|
         |___e___|
```

and

```
transform: translate(-50%, -100%)
```

works like so...

```
 _________________
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|     _______     |
|____|___e___|____|
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using a set width for the `.BottomMenu` class.

I have created a very basic [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLhugfox/) that demonstrates using a fixed width, margins and positioning to keep the div centered.

```
#bottom-menu {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  width:250px;
  margin-left:-125px;
  //optional
  padding: 10px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
}
```